# SVG ForeignObjects draw over all other elements in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, html5-canvas

**Update 22 April, 2016:** Nothing new, I just decided to check up on this, and post a quick code update. Firefox still performs as expected, IE doesn't perform at all, and Chrome 50.0.2661.87 m still behaves the same as it did last year. The fiddle link and code below have been updated to reflect the latest working version (in Firefox).

**Background:**
I'm playing with rendering a canvas + HTML elements to PNG. Of course, this means creating an interim SVG which hosts the HTML as a foreignObject.

The whole thing is a layer-cake of elements. I have a background, a layer of elements, the canvas, and another layer of elements.  You can see what it looks like in the snippet below.

I could have approached this in two ways:

1. Write everything, including the image, to a single SVG, which will be rendered to a canvas.
2. Write two SVGs, one for the background and the items behind the image, and another for the items in front of the image, then draw the back SVG, then the image, then the front SVG to the target canvas.

I chose option 1 because it seemed straightforward and simple.

**The problem:** SVG draw order is supposed to follow the DOM order, but in the case of Chrome (38 & Canary), it acts like it's rendering the foreignObjects *after* it renders the native objects, completely covering the native objects. (The code works as expected in Firefox, and fails miserably in IE11.) So who is correct? Is this a bug in Chrome, Firefox, or are neither of them handling this properly? Or is there some user error that I missed?

Thanks!

```js
function putAnImageInTheCanvas() {
  var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
  var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;
  svg.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
  svg.setAttribute('xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
  svg.setAttribute('height', '310');
  svg.setAttribute('width', '310');
  svg.setAttribute('version', '1.1');

  var svgRect = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'rect');
  svgRect.setAttribute('x', '125');
  svgRect.setAttribute('y', '25');
  svgRect.setAttribute('height', '250');
  svgRect.setAttribute('width', '50');
  svgRect.setAttribute('fill', 'rgb(0,255,255)');

  svg.appendChild(svgRect);

  var dataSrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(svg.outerHTML);

  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.setAttribute('src', dataSrc);

  var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 310, 310, 0, 0, 310, 310);
  });
}

function render(darwBackground) {
  var myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

  var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
  var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;
  svg.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
  svg.setAttribute('xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
  svg.setAttribute('height', '310');
  svg.setAttribute('width', '310');
  svg.setAttribute('version', '1.1');

  var background = document.getElementById('main').cloneNode();
  background.setAttribute("xmlns", document.documentElement.namespaceURI);
  var svgFO_BG = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'foreignObject');
  svgFO_BG.setAttribute('height', '310');
  svgFO_BG.setAttribute('width', '310');
  svgFO_BG.setAttribute('x', '0');
  svgFO_BG.setAttribute('y', '0');
  svgFO_BG.innerHTML = background.outerHTML.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|[\s]{2,})/gm, '');

  var back = document.getElementById('back').cloneNode(true);
  back.setAttribute("xmlns", document.documentElement.namespaceURI);
  var svgFO_AB = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'foreignObject');
  svgFO_AB.setAttribute('height', '310');
  svgFO_AB.setAttribute('width', '310');
  svgFO_AB.setAttribute('x', '0');
  svgFO_AB.setAttribute('y', '0');
  svgFO_AB.innerHTML = back.outerHTML.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|[\s]{2,})/gm, '');

  var front = document.getElementById('front').cloneNode(true);
  front.setAttribute("xmlns", document.documentElement.namespaceURI);
  var svgFO_AA = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'foreignObject');
  svgFO_AA.setAttribute('height', '310');
  svgFO_AA.setAttribute('width', '310');
  svgFO_AA.setAttribute('x', '0');
  svgFO_AA.setAttribute('y', '0');
  svgFO_AA.innerHTML = front.outerHTML.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|[\s]{2,})/gm, '');

  var svgImage = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'image');
  svgImage.setAttribute('xlink:href', myCanvas.toDataURL());
  svgImage.setAttribute('x', '0');
  svgImage.setAttribute('y', '0');
  svgImage.setAttribute('height', '310');
  svgImage.setAttribute('width', '310');

  var g = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'g');
  if (darwBackground) {
    g.appendChild(svgFO_BG);
    svg.appendChild(g);
  }

  g = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'g');
  g.appendChild(svgFO_AB);
  svg.appendChild(g);

  g = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'g');
  g.appendChild(svgImage);
  svg.appendChild(g);

  g = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'g');
  g.appendChild(svgFO_AA);
  svg.appendChild(g);

  var data = svg.outerHTML;

  document.getElementById('renderOutput').innerHTML = data;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="load canvas image" onclick="putAnImageInTheCanvas();" />
<input type="button" value="render with background" onclick="render(true);" />
<input type="button" value="render without background" onclick="render(false);" />
<h2>Preview:</h2>
<div id="main" style="border: 5px blue solid; width: 300px; height: 300px; background: yellow; position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; overflow: hidden;">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" height="300px" width="300px" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1;"></canvas>
  <div id="back" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;">
    <div style=" width: 100px; position: absolute; top: 75px; left: 75px; font-size: 20px; font-family: times; z-index: 0;">
      <div style="background: orange;">BACK</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="front" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;">
    <div style=" width: 100px; position: absolute; top: 150px; left: 150px; font-size: 20px; font-family: times; z-index: 2;">
      <div style="background: lime;">FRONT</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Render Result:</h2>
<div id="renderOutput">

</div>
```

Comment: I found the following [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=148499&q=svg%20foreignobject&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) which may be related.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried disabling hardware acceleration for canvases, and still saw the same issue. Still a problem in Chrome 48.0.2564.97 m.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't help me either.   Based on that and the latest comments in the bug I'm guessing it isn't a bug with the compositor but somewhere else in the chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooray! I'm not sure when the change came to be, but as of now, [the Chrome bug mentioned in the comments above](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=148499&q=svg%20foreignobject&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) has been resolved, which seems to have resolved the issue.

My demo now works in all major browsers:

- Chrome (69.0.3497.100)
- Firefox (62.0.2)
- Edge (38.14393.2068.0)

Answer (score -1):

This is still an issue in Chrome version 76 (canary) and official ver. 74.

The workaround I used was to place the canvas before the `svg`, not in the `foreignObject` inside it and wrap the whole content with a div with `position: relative` so the `svg` can be positioned `absolute` to be always above the canvas.

Also the wrapper div must have some additional css (flexbox in my case) so the canvas lays below the svg.

[See it on CodePen](https://codepen.io/jakub_antolak/pen/arPwPo)

```
    <div class="wrapper" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; display: flex; position: relative;">
      <canvas></canvas>
      <svg style="position: absolute" width="100%" height="100%">
        <g transform="translate(200, 200)">
          <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="30" fill="red"/>
          <text x="-12" y="2" font-family="Arial" font-size="15px" fill="black">SVG</text>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>

    <script>
      const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      canvas.width = 400;
      canvas.height = 400;

      ctx.fillStyle = "pink"
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      ctx.font = '20px Arial';
      ctx.fillText("Canvas", canvas.width / 2, 50);
    </script>
```

The con of this approach is you won't access any canvas mouse/screen event listeners if the canvas is covered by the svg at 100%.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the intent of the original effort: drawing layered HTML elements to a PNG, not just displaying them. This is done by putting the HTML into an SVG, drawing the SVG to a canvas, then getting the PNG data from the canvas. Your answer describes layering an SVG over a canvas, which is not what the question was asking.