# How can you have a background video in an SVG?

Tags: svg, html5-video

Using `foreignObject` you can use the `<video>` tag in an SVG,  like this:

```
<foreignObject width="100" height="100" x="10" y="250">
  <video xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="background: #ffffff; width: 150px; height: 50px;">
    <source src="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4"/>
  </video>
</foreignObject>
```

However, I cannot seem to make the video element obey the z-index rules in chrome.

In theory, the elements in the SVG should be rendered in order by their sequence in the group, and this does indeed, work for normal `foreignObject` tags, for example, this correctly renders the red, white and blue sections:

```
<rect x="10" y="10" width="200" height="200" fill="red"/>
<foreignObject width="100" height="100" x="10" y="50">
  <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="background: #ffffff; width: 150px; height: 50px;">
    Hello World
  </div>
</foreignObject>
<rect x="100" y="60" width="200" height="200" fill="blue"/>
```

...but once you stick a `<video>` in there, it just doesn't work any more.

Is this just a bug in chrome?

I looked through the bug tracker and although there are tonnes of SVG related bugs, the majority of the relevant ones were marked as resolved.

Am I doing something wrong? As far as I understand it, the order of the items in the `<g>` in the SVG should determine the z-index.

Below is a minimal reproducible test case.

(I also checked in firefox and it doesn't work there either...)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400px" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 400 600" version="1.1">
  <g>
    <path style="fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(72.54902%,100%,72.54902%);fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 0.636719 0.496094 L 593.5 0.496094 L 593.5 840.257812 L 0.636719 840.257812 Z M 0.636719 0.496094 "/>
    
    <!-- Order is correctly rendered by sequence of elements in SVG -->
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="200" height="200" fill="red"/>
    <foreignObject width="100" height="100" x="10" y="50">
      <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="background: #ffffff; width: 150px; height: 50px;">
        Hello World
      </div>
    </foreignObject>
    <rect x="100" y="60" width="200" height="200" fill="blue"/>

    <!-- Order is wrong for video element! -->
    <rect x="10" y="300" width="200" height="200" fill="red"/>
    <foreignObject width="100" height="100" x="10" y="250">
      <video xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="background: #ffffff; width: 150px; height: 50px;">
        <source src="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4"/>
      </video>
    </foreignObject>
    <rect x="100" y="360" width="200" height="200" fill="blue"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

According to me, this is a Chrome-bug and it still is in Chrome Version 72.0.3626.119 (Official Build) (64-bit); Firefox 65.0.1 (64-bit) renders it correctly. I used below test page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: grey;">
    <div style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px">
      <video width="480px" height="270px"  autoplay playinline muted loop src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
    </div>
    <svg width="1920px" height="1080px" style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px">
        <rect x=300 y=0 width=750 height=75 style="fill:rgb(255,20,20);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
        <foreignobject x=500 y=0 width=480 height=270>
            <video width="480px" height="270px"  autoplay playinline muted loop src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
        </foreignobject>
        <rect x=300 y=100 width=750 height=75 style="fill:rgb(20,255,20);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
        <foreignobject x=350 y=5 width=650 height=300>
            <div  style="width:480px; height:270px; font-size:20pt; border:6px; border-color:white;">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </foreignobject>
        <rect x=300 y=200 width=750 height=75 style="fill:rgb(20,20,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />  
    </svg>         
  </body>
</html>
```

Within an SVG block the (default) z-index should be according the order of specification of the inner elements (that's what the spec says). That applies also to `foreignobject`. [SVG ForeignObjects draw over all other elements in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348038/svg-foreignobjects-draw-over-all-other-elements-in-chrome) seems to be fixed partially. With a `<p>` in the `<foreignobject>` it works, with `<video>` it doesn't. You can draw SVG over a video when you place the whole `<SVG>` after the `<video>` and align them over each other with absolute positioning. Still, it should work within an `<foreignobject>` as well.